# Is it possible to configure kubectl port-forward to not exit on connection refused?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, socat

I am attempting to use the [socat gender change trick](https://superuser.com/a/1702203/109158) with the following commands, to allow code inside the pod to access google.com (as an example).

```
# Terminal 1
kubectl port-forward $POD 5432:5432

# Terminal 2
kubectl exec $POD -it -- bash
socat TCP-LISTEN:5431,reuseaddr,fork TCP-LISTEN:5432,reuseaddr

# Terminal 3
socat TCP:localhost:5432,forever,interval=1,fork TCP:google.com:443
```

Unfortunately, as soon as I start the command in Terminal 3, I get the error `address localhost: no suitable address found` followed by `lost connection to pod` in Terminal 1.

**Is it possible to configure `kubectl port-forward` to NOT exit after failing to make a connection?**

I've looked at `man kubectl-port-forward` but did not see any obvious flags for this.

Comment: Am I understanding this correctly: (1) forwards from `localhost:5432` to `${POD}:5432`; (2) the Pod forwards (bidirectional) `5431` <----> `5432`; (3) attempts to forward from (!) `localhost:5432` to `google.com:443`? It seems like #3 replaces #1. IIUC you're trying to gain access to google.com **from** the Pod. If so, you want to port-forward from the Pod to localhost.`kubectl port-forward` is **not** bidrectional.

Comment: @DazWilkin I realize that kubectl port-forward is not bidirectional, but I am trying to use the `socat` gender change to get bidirectional traffic. See the linked question for more details on the technique I'm trying to use.

Comment: Indeed but #1 binds localhost:5432 to one remote port and #3 binds localhost:5432 to a different remote port. You can't bind the same local port to different remote ports.

Comment: Terminal 3 is trying to *connect* to localhost:5432, while Terminal 1 is LISTENING on localhost:5432. Those actions are not mutually exclusive.

Also, the question isn't presenting a problem with my laptop; it's a problem with `kubectl port-forward`, which ceases port-forwarding on the first failure to connect.

Comment: It might help to change the sub command (2) to: socat TCP-LISTEN:5432,reuseaddr,fork TCP-LISTEN:5431,reuseaddr; because the first listener is always on, the second listener only when the first has accepted a connection. And, start (2) before (1) !

Comment: @dest-unreach, I actually did try reversing the order of the arguments on the second terminal. However, the repeated connection attempts from Terminal 3 causes the Terminal 2 command to attempt to `LISTEN` on `5431`, and every attempt after the first one fails.